# Sound doesn't play when pressing button?

Tags: android, audio, media-player

So at the moment I have implemented this code:

final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
            }
            try {

                AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                afd = getAssets().openFd("pop.mp3");
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

no errors at all. App starts and works normally but even though the above method has been implemented I hear no sound at all.

Here's the rest of my code:

```
public class MyActivity2 extends Activity {
private String[] colors;
private String[] values;
private TextView tv;
private RelativeLayout rl;
Button n;
int index = 0;
int position2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity2);
    n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_view);

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    n.setTypeface(typeface);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OSP-DIN.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);

    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
            }
            try {

                AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                afd = getAssets().openFd("Facebook Chat 'pop' Sound 3.mp3");
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
    });
            values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.allthings_array);
            colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorcode_array);

            n.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            if (index == 5) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "More coming soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                position2 = (index++);
                            }
                            String textValue = values[position2];
                            tv.setText(textValue);
                            Random RAND = new Random();
                            int position = RAND.nextInt(colors.length);
                            String nextValue = colors[position];
                            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(nextValue));
                            n.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(00, 00, 00, 00));
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            n.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(00, 00, 00, 00));
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation4, R.anim.animation3);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors? You should add a `catch (Exception e)` clause just in case.

Comment: Yeah - like how you've done in the "here's the rest of my code part" except with an e.printStackTrace() between the brackets.

Comment: That code will hit a state 128 error if the file finishes playing before the next click. If you check the state diagram you'll see that PlaybackComplete is not .isPlaying() but the only way to get back to state Idle is .reset(). So you'll be in PlaybackComplete, and not playing so you won't reset and then try to .setDataSource() while not in Idle. Move the mp.reset(); out of that bracket and always do it.

Answer (score 0):

At first I advise you to create a new folder in the res folder which has the name of raw ,and then put your audio file in this folder.

And after that write this code source in the onClick method :

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           // mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop);
           mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
           mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();

        }
    });
```

;